# Why is FindIndex in my LINQ expression not working?

Tags: c#, linq

My program creates a list, populates it with `Person` objects, and attempts to find the index of the *next* object that has the same name as the first object in the list.  Knowing where that particular index is, the program can split the original list into two different list.  For some reason, though, the LINQ expression is returning zero for the `splitLocation` when I'm expecting it to return a value of five.  Apparently, I'm doing the LINQ expression wrong, or I'm not understanding how I'm supposed to be using `FindIndex`.  Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NeedleInHaystack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create the 'haystack'
            var people = new List<Person>();
            var person1 = new Person("Frank");
            var person2 = new Person("Jules");
            var person3 = new Person("Mark");
            var person4 = new Person("Allan");
            var person5 = new Person("Frank");
            var person6 = new Person("Greg");
            var person7 = new Person("Tim");
            people.Add(person1);
            people.Add(person2);
            people.Add(person3);
            people.Add(person4);
            people.Add(person5);
            people.Add(person6);
            people.Add(person7);

            // here's the 'needle'
            var needle = people[0].Name;

            var listA = new List<Person>();
            var listB = new List<Person>();

            // find the needle in the haystack
            var splitLocation = people.FindIndex(person => person.Name.Equals(needle));
            listA = people.Take(splitLocation).ToList();
            listB = people.Skip(splitLocation).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the *next* item that has the same name as the *first* item, but you're not skipping the first item!   Use the overload of [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that includes the starting location:

```
var splitLocation = people.FindIndex(1, person => person.Name.Equals(needle));
```

Note that it will return `-1` if no match is found, so your `Take` will blow up.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I wasn't aware of the overload for FirstIndex that would let me specify a starting index.  I didn't even think to look.  I greatly appreciate your help!